# rdd.map invoking a function twice rather than once

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am a newbie to scala programming and I am currently working with RDD. I am trying to pass an RDD to a function and would like the function to return so that I can store it to a new RDD. For the purpose I am using map. But map is invoking the function twice whereas there is only one entry inside the RDD. It works fine when I used collect.foreach() instead of map but I am unable to save the updates values in  a new RDD as its returning a value in Unit.

This code returns the value from the update function but invokes the function twice:

```
temp_rdd = my_rdd.map{x => update(x)}
```

Whereas this one invokes it once perfectly but i cannot modify the RDD values:

```
my_rdd.collect().foreach{x => update(x)}
```

The foreach function returns a format in 'Unit' due to ehich I cannot save it in a new RDD. I am looking for a way to store the updated values in a new RDD.

Comment: Function will be called as many times as number of "temp_rdd" actions will be called. Every time when "temp_rdd" materialized, function will be called. For ex., if call action "temp_rdd.collect()" three times, all transformations ("map" in this case) will be called three times. For avoid this, caching can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html

`map` is a **transformation** that passes each dataset element through a function and returns a new RDD representing the results. All transformations in Spark are lazy, and are computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program. By default, each transformed RDD may be recomputed each time you run an action on it (or you can persist the RDD in memory using the `.cache()`).

On the other hand, **actions** (e.g., `collect` or `reduce`) return a value (not an RDD) to the driver program after running a computation on the RDD.

Here follows an example of caching an RDD in order to prevent its computation multiple times

```
val array = Array("1", "2", "3")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(array)
var i = 0
val mapRdd = rdd.map(s"$i: " + _)
mapRdd.take(3).foreach(println) // mapRdd is computed here...
// Output
// 0: 1
// 0: 2
// 0: 3

i = i + 1
mapRdd.take(3).foreach(println) // ... and here
// Output
// 1: 1
// 1: 2
// 1: 3

val cachedMapRdd = rdd.map(s"$i: " + _).cache()
cachedMapRdd.take(3).foreach(println) // cachedMapRdd is computed here...
// Output
// 1: 1
// 1: 2
// 1: 3

i = i + 1
cachedMapRdd.take(3).foreach(println) // ... but not here
// Output
// 1: 1
// 1: 2
// 1: 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have implemented my program by using .cache() and my problem has been solved. I have set 2 worker nodes but the execution of my program is taking place in a single worker and not parallely in 2 workers. Any suggestions for this issue?